# Audio streaming with Android MediaPlayer

Tags: android, audio, mp3, media-player, shoutcast

I'm trying to create an audio streamer with Android's MediaPlayer. It's just fine if it doesn't work with Android 2.1 or bellow. I need to be able to play the audio from a SHOUTcast stream. Here's my code:

```
player = new MediaPlayer();
try {
player.setDataSource("http://87.230.103.107:8000");
player.prepareAsync();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
player.start();
```

For some reason, this code will play just nothing. I think it may be related to the app permissions. Does anyone know what's going on?

Thanks!

[UPDATE]
I'm getting the following errors:

```
04-25 23:35:15.432: ERROR/MediaPlayer(283): start called in state 4
04-25 23:35:15.432: ERROR/MediaPlayer(283): error (-38, 0)
04-25 23:35:15.602: ERROR/MediaPlayer(283): Error (-38,0)
04-25 23:35:17.542: INFO/AwesomePlayer(33): calling prefetcher->prepare()
04-25 23:35:18.547: INFO/Prefetcher(33): [0x17650] cache below low water mark, filling cache.
04-25 23:35:18.762: INFO/AwesomePlayer(33): prefetcher is done preparing
04-25 23:35:19.769: ERROR/AwesomePlayer(33): Not sending buffering status because duration is unknown.
```

Comment: Are you running this in the emulator? I've had problems running media in the emulator before. Try it in an actual device, maybe it will work.

Comment: Yes, I'm running it on the emulator. Too bad I don't have a real device :(

Comment: My hunch is that that's the problem. Someone else might have another take.

Comment: Just for kicks, set your data source to `http://87.230.103.107:8000/;`.  If it works, it means your user-agent is Mozilla, which causes the SHOUTcast server to send back the admin interface rather than the stream.  The semicolon forces it to return the stream.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for the late response, ran across this while looking for answers to another problem.

If you still need an answer, you're calling `start()` while it's still being prepared. `PrepareAsync()` returns immediately, unlike `prepare()`. The problem with using 'prepare()` with streams is that it will block until it has enough data to start play.

What you want to do is set an `OnPreparedListener`, and have the `start()` called from there.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that content type "audio/aacp" streaming is not supported directly . Some decoding library can be sued to play "aacp", please see the solution below:

[Freeware Advanced Audio (AAC) Decoder for Android](http://code.google.com/p/aacplayer-android/)

[How to use this library?](http://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/source/browse/trunk/player/src/com/spoledge/aacplay/AACPlayerActivity.java)

For more detail please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681550/android-2-2-mediaplayer-is-working-fine-with-one-shoutcast-url-but-not-with-the).

**[Consider legal issues while using it](http://vaclavb.blogspot.com/2010/06/raw-aac-player-for-android.html).**

> - the project http://code.google.com/p/aacplayer-android/ is licensed
>     under GPL, so you can create commercial apps   * on top of it, but you
>     need to fullfill the GPL - mainly it means to publish your code as
>     well.  * If you use the second project
>     http://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/ , then you do not need to
>     publish your   * code (the library is licensed under LGPL).

Answer (score -1):

1)Avoid using prepare(), use prepareAsyc() instead.  (or) put your playing logic in a worked thread or a separate thread.  1)Avoid using player.prepare(), instead use player.prepareAsync();

(or) keep the logic in a separate thread. (you can use intent service, AsyncTask,etc)

2)Also try with static constructor MediaPlayer.create(Uri);