# Android 2.2 MediaPlayer is working fine with one SHOUTcast URL but not with the other one

Tags: android, media-player, uri, audio-streaming, shoutcast

Please see the code i am using for streaming shoutcast stream, it works with one URL but NOT with the other one.

This one works:

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse("http://fr3.ah.fm:9000/");
```

But not with this one:

```
Uri myUri =  Uri.parse("http://someOtherURL");
```

SimpleMusicStream.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SimpleMusicStream extends Activity implements
  MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,
  MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener {

 private String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
 private MediaPlayer mp = null;

 private Button play;
 private Button pause;
 private Button stop;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
  super.onCreate(icicle);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
  pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
  stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);

  play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View view) {
    play();
   }
  });

  pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View view) {
    pause();
   }
  });

  stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View view) {
    stop();
   }
  });
 }

 private void play() {
  Uri myUri = Uri.parse("http://fr3.ah.fm:9000/");
  try {
   if (mp == null) {
    this.mp = new MediaPlayer();
   } else {
    mp.stop();
    mp.reset();
   }
   mp.setDataSource(this, myUri); // Go to Initialized state
   mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
   mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
   mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);

   mp.setOnErrorListener(this);
   mp.prepareAsync();

   Log.d(TAG, "LoadClip Done");
  } catch (Throwable t) {
   Log.d(TAG, t.toString());
  }
 }

 @Override
 public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
  Log.d(TAG, "Stream is prepared");
  mp.start();
 }

 private void pause() {
  mp.pause();
 }

 private void stop() {
  mp.stop();

 }

 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  stop();

 }

 public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
  stop();
 }

 public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.append("Media Player Error: ");
  switch (what) {
  case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK:
   sb.append("Not Valid for Progressive Playback");
   break;
  case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
   sb.append("Server Died");
   break;
  case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
   sb.append("Unknown");
   break;
  default:
   sb.append(" Non standard (");
   sb.append(what);
   sb.append(")");
  }
  sb.append(" (" + what + ") ");
  sb.append(extra);
  Log.e(TAG, sb.toString());
  return true;
 }

 public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
  Log.d(TAG, "PlayerService onBufferingUpdate : " + percent + "%");
 }

    }
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <Button
  android:text="Play"
  android:id="@+id/play"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
 <Button
  android:text="Pause"
  android:id="@+id/pause"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
 <Button
  android:text="Stop"
  android:id="@+id/stop"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

**The Log-cat shows errors:**

```
NuHTTPDataSource(33): Server did not give us the content length!

Media Player Error: Unknown (1) -2147483648
Media Player Error: Unknown (1) -1002
```

Can someone help me to fix it?

**EDIT:**

Just to share with you people, that our [current code works with Android 2.1 & minor versions, but not works with Android 2.2 or higher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671479/android-mediaplayer-setdatasource-works-fine-in-our-custom-audio-streaming-app).

Thanks

Comment: Based on some quick Googling it's the audio encoding ``audio/aacp`` causing some headache for others too.

Comment: Another really good discussion can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650983/server-side-aac-audio-with-android

Comment: help me at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264225/andriod-shoutcast-internet-radio-filenotfoundexception

Comment: Could you share with me  the Source Code for ShoutCast URL Streaming Andriod?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shoutcast mp3 streaming from Android 2.2 onwards is supported natively .

Below 2.2 the Android OS cannot play shoutcast streams natively without using a proxy on the stream end or a stream proxy class on the device to capture the stream and pass it to the audioplayer just like [NPR](http://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/source/checkout) does.

audio/aacp streaming is not supported directly . For this you can use ffmpeg, opencore or faad2 library to decode it into PCM and play using audiotrack .[Reference](http://code.google.com/p/aacplayer-android/)

Comment: Shoutcast  streams are supported from 2.2 onwards i know that but why it works with one of url & not working the other one?

Comment: As I said only Shoutcast mp3 streaming is supported from Android 2.2 . One of your url is of content type "audio/aacp" which is I guess not playing, another one is "audio/mpeg" which is supported in android 2.2 onwards. For AACP either you have save the content in file and then play Or use any decoding libraries which I mentioned..But also consider legal issues while using it.

Comment: @SanthoshShettigar help me at this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264225/andriod-shoutcast-internet-radio-filenotfoundexception

Answer (score 1):

problem is encoding in audio/aacp

Problem is that aacp is not rendered by Android Media Player properly. You will have to try some other codec or write your own decoder.

Comment: please help me at this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264225/andriod-shoutcast-internet-radio-filenotfoundexception @the100rabh

Answer (score 1):

`Mediaplayer` supports only [these formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) as given in the android developer documents.

Some streams may be satisfying this,but some will not

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Freeware Advanced Audio (AAC) Decoder for Android](https://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/). You can use this for help and Guidance or use Multiplayer class in it to playback aac audio. There is a sample app and library in it to help you understand. I have used this library to play Shoutcast online Streams. I played both AAC and MP3 using Multiplayer class provided in the library

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i got simple shoutcast streaming app. 
Try [this](https://github.com/cr5315/shoutcast-android). Just change streaming url in **StreamService.java**.