# Android app gets slow when I change audio streaming stations

Tags: android, performance, audio, stream, media-player

I hope someone can help me with this.

Here's y problem: I have an icecast server with a couple of channels. I developed an app to listen those stations but when I change from one station to another one the app gets really slow.

Here's the code to change the station:

```
public static void setAndPlay(MediaPlayer player, String source) {
        player.reset();
        try {
            player.setDataSource(source);
            player.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //TODO: handle exception
        }
}
```

And here's when the mediaPlayer starts:

```
player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
                player.start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: What does `player.reset()` do?

Comment: After reset(), the object is like being just created.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful [link](http://developer.android.com/images/mediaplayer_state_diagram.gif)

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SimpleMusicStream extends Activity implements
  MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,
  MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener {

 private String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
 private MediaPlayer mp = null;

 private Button play;
 private Button pause;
 private Button stop;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
  super.onCreate(icicle);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
  pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
  stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);

  play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View view) {
    play();
   }
  });

  pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View view) {
    pause();
   }
  });

  stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View view) {
    stop();
   }
  });
 }

 private void play() {
  Uri myUri = Uri.parse("http://fr3.ah.fm:9000/");
  try {
   if (mp == null) {
    this.mp = new MediaPlayer();
   } else {
    mp.stop();
    mp.reset();
   }
   mp.setDataSource(this, myUri); // Go to Initialized state
   mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
   mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
   mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);

   mp.setOnErrorListener(this);
   mp.prepareAsync();

   Log.d(TAG, "LoadClip Done");
  } catch (Throwable t) {
   Log.d(TAG, t.toString());
  }
 }

 @Override
 public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
  Log.d(TAG, "Stream is prepared");
  mp.start();
 }

 private void pause() {
  mp.pause();
 }

 private void stop() {
  mp.stop();

 }

 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  stop();

 }

 public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
  stop();
 }

 public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.append("Media Player Error: ");
  switch (what) {
  case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK:
   sb.append("Not Valid for Progressive Playback");
   break;
  case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
   sb.append("Server Died");
   break;
  case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
   sb.append("Unknown");
   break;
  default:
   sb.append(" Non standard (");
   sb.append(what);
   sb.append(")");
  }
  sb.append(" (" + what + ") ");
  sb.append(extra);
  Log.e(TAG, sb.toString());
  return true;
 }

 public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
  Log.d(TAG, "PlayerService onBufferingUpdate : " + percent + "%");
 }

    }
```

**main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <Button
  android:text="Play"
  android:id="@+id/play"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
 <Button
  android:text="Pause"
  android:id="@+id/pause"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
 <Button
  android:text="Stop"
  android:id="@+id/stop"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can find it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681550/android-2-2-mediaplayer-is-working-fine-with-one-shoutcast-url-but-not-with-the

Comment: Thank you, it resolved part of the problem. Now the app doesn't get slow, but I need the music to start faster. How can I do that?