# ANDROID : how to stream and play .m4a audio file in application

Tags: android, audio-streaming

I have a URL from where I have to stream and play ".m4a" audio file in my application. After searching for this for almost a week I have come up with no solution.

This is the URL of the ".m4a" audio file.
http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/044/Music/e9/40/ec/mzm.evyxvimp.aac.p.m4a

I don't want to download the song and play(that I have done). Issue is I want to just stream and play.

can anyone please guide me how to do this? plz lemme know if there is any link/ref to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Some decoding libraries please see the solution below:

[Freeware Advanced Audio (AAC) Decoder for Android](http://code.google.com/p/aacplayer-android/)

[How to use this library?](http://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/source/browse/trunk/player/src/com/spoledge/aacplay/AACPlayerActivity.java)

**[Consider legal issues while using it](http://vaclavb.blogspot.com/2010/06/raw-aac-player-for-android.html).**

> [T]he project http://code.google.com/p/aacplayer-android/ is licensed
>   under GPL, so you can create commercial apps  on top of it, but you
>   need to fullfill the GPL - mainly it means to publish your code as
>   well.   If you use the second project
>   http://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/ , then you do not need to
>   publish your   code (the library is licensed under LGPL).

**For more detail please see these questions:**

[Android MediaPlayer works fine in our Custom audio Streaming application up to Android 2.1 but not in higher versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671479/android-mediaplayer-works-fine-in-our-custom-audio-streaming-application-up-to-a)

[Android 2.2 MediaPlayer is working fine with one SHOUTcast URL but not with the other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681550/android-2-2-mediaplayer-is-working-fine-with-one-shoutcast-url-but-not-with-the)

Comment: I have not been able to use this library to stream MP4-encoded AAC+ streams.  It only works with raw AAC or MP3.