# Android Custom Video Player

Tags: android, android-video-player

I have an application that streams videos from my server. The thing is I don't get enough out of the ads displayed on the app as the time spent in my app is very less compared to  the time spent while watching videos. So, I was thinking of integrating my own custom video player to the app I made and display banner ads in it while the video is streaming.

How can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- You need to use the MediaPlayer class like [its used here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681550/android-2-2-mediaplayer-is-working-fine-with-one-shoutcast-url-but-not-with-the).

2- [Use the Google AdMob Ads SDK](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html), [example is here](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html#adactivity).