# Android mediaplayer radio streaming with wma codec

Tags: android, audio, streaming

I'm trying to play radio audio stream from the media player in android 4.0.3 API15.
Some of the stations work, but a lot of the stations fail, for example :

http://switch3.castup.net/cunet/gm.asp?ai=31&ar=88FM

This station(and many other) is returning me the following error:
error (1,-21477483648).

I checked the codec being used in that station and its wma.
The media player doesnt support this codec but i know that there is application("Radio Israel") that can play this station.

My question is , is there any workaround for playing that stream?
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681550/android-2-2-mediaplayer-is-working-fine-with-one-shoutcast-url-but-not-with-the

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671479/android-mediaplayer-works-fine-in-our-custom-audio-streaming-application-up-to-a

Answer (score 0):

WMA is a Windows format and Android is Linux. You could use a proxy server of your own to encode into MP3 (or another format) then stream from there.

Comment: Do you know if there is a utility or an open source library for android that can encode a given stream?