# pause called in state 0

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

This is my code:

---

```
  playbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {
                    public void onClick(View arg0) 
                    {    
                     if(play==false)
                  {
                     playbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pausebutton); 
                     play=true;
                     tb_tan.setClickable(false);
                     mp.start();
                  }
                  else
                 {
                      playbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playbutton); 
                      play=false;
                      mp.pause();
                      if(mp1.isPlaying())
                      {
                      mp1.pause();
                      }
                      tb_tan.setClickable(true);        
                  }         
                     }                              
                });
```

---

and whenever I click **PAUSE** button I get this error "**PAUSE CALLED IN STATE 0**".
Can Anyone please help?

Comment: Format your questions. Also, don't caps, ever.

Comment: See if this answers your question. Also make sure to put your code in code format blocks, hard to read otherwise. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008770/media-player-called-in-state-0-error-38-0

Comment: You haven't posted all relevant code. See similar threads here on SO

Comment: it worked! thanks:)i used  mp.setOnErrorListener(errorListener); and it worked:):)

Comment: Does it play sound when you click pause button.