# Android MediaPlayer Error (-38, 0) "stop called in state 0"

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have looked at various different websites looking for a solution for this problem in my code. It is a basic audio player with 3 buttons: play, pause and stop. Play and pause work ok and so does stop but once the audio has been stopped it refuses to start again, throwing an error:

```
E/MediaPlayer: stop called in state 0
E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
```

This is my MainActivity.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {

    static Button playButton;
    static Button pauseButton;
    static Button stopButton;
    static SeekBar seekBar;
    private static MediaPlayer player;
static Handler handler;
static Uri audio;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.airbourne_runnin_wild);
    Uri audio = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.airbourne_runnin_wild);
    try {
        player.setDataSource(getAssets().openFd("raw/airbourne_runnin_wild.mp3").getFileDescriptor());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
    pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);
    stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

    player.setOnPreparedListener(this);

    handler = new Handler();

    seekBar.setMax(player.getDuration());

    playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!player.isPlaying()) {
                try {
                    player.setDataSource(getAssets().openFd("raw/airbourne_runnin_wild.mp3").getFileDescriptor());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                player.start();
                updateSeekBar();
            }
        }
    });

    pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (player.isPlaying()) {
                player.pause();
            }
        }
    });

    stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (player.isPlaying()) {
                player.stop();
                seekBar.setProgress(0);
                seekBar.invalidate();
                try {
                    player.setDataSource(getAssets().openFd("raw/airbourne_runnin_wild.mp3").getFileDescriptor());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
            if (b) {
                seekChanged(seekBar, i, b);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

    player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            player.stop();
            seekBar.setProgress(0);
            //player.prepareAsync();
            seekBar.invalidate();
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    playButton.setEnabled(true);
}

public void seekChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    player.seekTo(progress);
}

public void updateSeekBar() {
    seekBar.setProgress(player.getCurrentPosition());

    if (player.isPlaying()) {
        Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                updateSeekBar();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(notification, 1500);
    }
}
}
```

And activity_main.xml:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Play"
            android:id="@+id/playButton"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_column="8"
            android:enabled="false"/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pause"
            android:id="@+id/pauseButton"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_column="8"
            android:layout_span="7"/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Stop"
            android:id="@+id/stopButton"
            android:layout_column="8"
            android:layout_span="24"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</TableRow>

<TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_column="8"
            android:layout_span="24"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
</TableRow>
```

If anyone could help me resolve this error, it would be much appreciated. I have already searched round for solutions and tried multiple, but none seemed to work properly.

EDIT: I changed a little bit of the code:

My question is still about the error, and this is now my edited code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {

static Button playButton;
static Button pauseButton;
static Button stopButton;
static SeekBar seekBar;
private static MediaPlayer player;
static Handler handler;
static Uri audio;
static boolean canMakeCall = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.airbourne_runnin_wild);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
    pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);
    stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

    if (canMakeCall = true) {
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);

        handler = new Handler();

        seekBar.setMax(player.getDuration());

        playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!player.isPlaying()) {
                    player.start();
                    updateSeekBar();
                }
            }
        });

        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (player.isPlaying()) {
                    player.pause();
                }
            }
        });

        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (player.isPlaying()) {
                    player.stop();
                    seekBar.setProgress(0);
                    seekBar.invalidate();
                    try {
                        player.prepare();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                if (b) {
                    seekChanged(seekBar, i, b);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

        player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                //player.stop();

                seekBar.setProgress(0);
                //player.prepareAsync();
                seekBar.invalidate();
            }
        });
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    playButton.setEnabled(true);
    canMakeCall = true;
}

public void seekChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    player.seekTo(progress);
}

public void updateSeekBar() {
    seekBar.setProgress(player.getCurrentPosition());

    if (player.isPlaying()) {
        Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                updateSeekBar();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(notification, 1500);
    }
}
}
```

I have tried getting the basics working without a seekbar too, just to make sure that isn't causing an error but it lies somewhere within the logic of the play/pause/stop code because it was producing the same error even with the seekbar code omitted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android MediaPlayer Problems :"Error (-38 , 0) " and "stop called in state 1"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913108/android-mediaplayer-problems-error-38-0-and-stop-called-in-state-1)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is once you've stopped it, you `setDataSource` again. You have to then call `prepare()`

```
player.setDataSource(getAssets().openFd("raw/airbourne_runnin_wild.mp3").getFileDescriptor());
player.prepare();
```

Anytime you call `setDataSource()` on it you will need to `prepare()` it again. Think of it as loading the file, getting ready for playback.

By the way I notice you mix up calling `MediaPlayer.create()` and also call `setDataSource()` multiple times for the same file. There's no need to do this. Once the MediaPlayer is created and prepared (which calling `.create()` does for you), you can just call `.stop()`, `.pause()`, `.play()` on it, no need to reset it all the time.

Comment: I've just changed the code to remove the .setDataSource and the associated try...catch statements but the code is still producing the same error. When I press play, it begins to play fine and the SeekBar moves along fine, pause works fine too and then I stop it but the seekbar doesn't reset to zero for some reason either, thats where the errors begin.

Comment: It's difficult to say what's going on now that you've changed code, and it doesn't match your question, and there's no stacktrace with line number to see. I'm not unsure whether your question is about your seekbar or about the original error of stop being called in the wrong state. If I were you I would get the basics working without any seekbar.

Comment: Please see my edits above, the reply took a while too because the DNS server died at my work.

Comment: I solved this problem: in the `player.setOnCompletionListener()` I was calling `player.stop()` yet the player had already stopped.

Comment: Cool! I noticed that but didn't realise `onCompletion` got called when you hit stop. MediaPlayer is picky about states, that's for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by removing the `player.stop()` which was being called when the player finished the song because of `player.setOnCompletionListener()`. This has now resolved the problem and the player is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by `mediaPlayer.prepare(); My problem is about live radio streaming and I achieve this problem like below code:

```
if (!radioIsOpen) {
                try {
                    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    mediaPlayer
                            .setDataSource(URL);
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                });
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio is opening...", 2).show();
            } else {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio is closing...", 2).show();
                }
            }
```