# how to resolve Media player error(-38,0)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have used media player in my android application.That plays 3gp files but if i play mp4 or other formats it shows MediaPlayer error (-38, 0) and MediaPlayer error (1, -2147483648) errors.can anybody help me to solve this problem?

```
public class VideoPlayerActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, VideoControllerView.MediaPlayerControl {

SurfaceView videoSurface;
MediaPlayer player;
VideoControllerView controller;
TextView txtvalue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    registerBaseActivityReceiver();
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player);

    String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");

    txtvalue=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.value);

    videoSurface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.videoSurface);
    SurfaceHolder videoHolder = videoSurface.getHolder();
    videoHolder.addCallback(this);

    player = new MediaPlayer();
    controller = new VideoControllerView(this);

    try {
        txtvalue.setText(value);
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        player.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(value));
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unRegisterBaseActivityReceiver();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    controller.show();
    return false;
}

// Implement SurfaceHolder.Callback
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    player.setDisplay(holder);
    player.prepareAsync();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

}
// End SurfaceHolder.Callback

// Implement MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    controller.setMediaPlayer(this);
    controller.setAnchorView((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.videoSurfaceContainer));
    player.start();
}
// End MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener

// Implement VideoMediaController.MediaPlayerControl
@Override
public boolean canPause() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean canSeekBackward() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean canSeekForward() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public int getBufferPercentage() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getCurrentPosition() {
    return player.getCurrentPosition();
}

@Override
public int getDuration() {
    return player.getDuration();
}

@Override
public boolean isPlaying() {
    return player.isPlaying();
}

@Override
public void pause() {
    player.pause();
}

@Override
public void seekTo(int i) {
    player.seekTo(i);
}

@Override
public void start() {
    player.start();
}

@Override
public boolean isFullScreen() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void toggleFullScreen() {

}
// End VideoMediaController.MediaPlayerControl
```

}

```
public class VideoControllerView extends FrameLayout {
private static final String TAG = "VideoControllerView";

private MediaPlayerControl  mPlayer;
private Context             mContext;
private ViewGroup           mAnchor;
private View                mRoot;
private ProgressBar         mProgress;
private TextView            mEndTime, mCurrentTime;
private boolean             mShowing;
private boolean             mDragging;
private static final int    sDefaultTimeout = 3000;
private static final int    FADE_OUT = 1;
private static final int    SHOW_PROGRESS = 2;
private boolean             mUseFastForward;
private boolean             mFromXml;
private boolean             mListenersSet;
private View.OnClickListener mNextListener, mPrevListener;
StringBuilder               mFormatBuilder;
Formatter                   mFormatter;
private ImageButton         mPauseButton;
private ImageButton         mFfwdButton;
private ImageButton         mRewButton;
private ImageButton         mNextButton;
private ImageButton         mPrevButton;
private ImageButton         mFullscreenButton;
private Handler             mHandler = new MessageHandler(this);

public VideoControllerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mRoot = null;
    mContext = context;
    mUseFastForward = true;
    mFromXml = true;

    Log.i(TAG, TAG);
}

public VideoControllerView(Context context, boolean useFastForward) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    mUseFastForward = useFastForward;

    Log.i(TAG, TAG);
}

public VideoControllerView(Context context) {
    this(context, true);

    Log.i(TAG, TAG);
}

@Override
public void onFinishInflate() {
    if (mRoot != null)
        initControllerView(mRoot);
}

public void setMediaPlayer(MediaPlayerControl player) {
    mPlayer = player;
    updatePausePlay();
    updateFullScreen();
}

/**
 * Set the view that acts as the anchor for the control view.
 * This can for example be a VideoView, or your Activity's main view.
 * @param view The view to which to anchor the controller when it is visible.
 */
public void setAnchorView(ViewGroup view) {
    mAnchor = view;

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );

    removeAllViews();
    View v = makeControllerView();
    addView(v, frameParams);
}

/**
 * Create the view that holds the widgets that control playback.
 * Derived classes can override this to create their own.
 * @return The controller view.
 * @hide This doesn't work as advertised
 */
protected View makeControllerView() {
    LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mRoot = inflate.inflate(R.layout.media_controller, null);

    initControllerView(mRoot);

    return mRoot;
}

private void initControllerView(View v) {
    mPauseButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.pause);
    if (mPauseButton != null) {
        mPauseButton.requestFocus();
        mPauseButton.setOnClickListener(mPauseListener);
    }

    mFullscreenButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen);
    if (mFullscreenButton != null) {
        mFullscreenButton.requestFocus();
        mFullscreenButton.setOnClickListener(mFullscreenListener);
    }

    mFfwdButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.ffwd);
    if (mFfwdButton != null) {
        mFfwdButton.setOnClickListener(mFfwdListener);
        if (!mFromXml) {
            mFfwdButton.setVisibility(mUseFastForward ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
    }

    mRewButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.rew);
    if (mRewButton != null) {
        mRewButton.setOnClickListener(mRewListener);
        if (!mFromXml) {
            mRewButton.setVisibility(mUseFastForward ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
    }

    // By default these are hidden. They will be enabled when setPrevNextListeners() is called 
    mNextButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.next);
    if (mNextButton != null && !mFromXml && !mListenersSet) {
        mNextButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    mPrevButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.prev);
    if (mPrevButton != null && !mFromXml && !mListenersSet) {
        mPrevButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    mProgress = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.mediacontroller_progress);
    if (mProgress != null) {
        if (mProgress instanceof SeekBar) {
            SeekBar seeker = (SeekBar) mProgress;
            seeker.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(mSeekListener);
        }
        mProgress.setMax(1000);
    }

    mEndTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time);
    mCurrentTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time_current);
    mFormatBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    mFormatter = new Formatter(mFormatBuilder, Locale.getDefault());

    installPrevNextListeners();
}

/**
 * Show the controller on screen. It will go away
 * automatically after 3 seconds of inactivity.
 */
public void show() {
    show(sDefaultTimeout);
}

/**
 * Disable pause or seek buttons if the stream cannot be paused or seeked.
 * This requires the control interface to be a MediaPlayerControlExt
 */
private void disableUnsupportedButtons() {
    if (mPlayer == null) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        if (mPauseButton != null && !mPlayer.canPause()) {
            mPauseButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
        if (mRewButton != null && !mPlayer.canSeekBackward()) {
            mRewButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
        if (mFfwdButton != null && !mPlayer.canSeekForward()) {
            mFfwdButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    } catch (IncompatibleClassChangeError ex) {
        // We were given an old version of the interface, that doesn't have
        // the canPause/canSeekXYZ methods. This is OK, it just means we
        // assume the media can be paused and seeked, and so we don't disable
        // the buttons.
    }
}

/**
 * Show the controller on screen. It will go away
 * automatically after 'timeout' milliseconds of inactivity.
 * @param timeout The timeout in milliseconds. Use 0 to show
 * the controller until hide() is called.
 */
public void show(int timeout) {
    if (!mShowing && mAnchor != null) {
        setProgress();
        if (mPauseButton != null) {
            mPauseButton.requestFocus();
        }
        disableUnsupportedButtons();

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams tlp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            Gravity.BOTTOM
        );

        mAnchor.addView(this, tlp);
        mShowing = true;
    }
    updatePausePlay();
    updateFullScreen();

    // cause the progress bar to be updated even if mShowing
    // was already true.  This happens, for example, if we're
    // paused with the progress bar showing the user hits play.
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(SHOW_PROGRESS);

    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(FADE_OUT);
    if (timeout != 0) {
        mHandler.removeMessages(FADE_OUT);
        mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, timeout);
    }
}

public boolean isShowing() {
    return mShowing;
}

/**
 * Remove the controller from the screen.
 */
public void hide() {
    if (mAnchor == null) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        mAnchor.removeView(this);
        mHandler.removeMessages(SHOW_PROGRESS);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.w("MediaController", "already removed");
    }
    mShowing = false;
}

private String stringForTime(int timeMs) {
    int totalSeconds = timeMs / 1000;

    int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
    int minutes = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60;
    int hours   = totalSeconds / 3600;

    mFormatBuilder.setLength(0);
    if (hours > 0) {
        return mFormatter.format("%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds).toString();
    } else {
        return mFormatter.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds).toString();
    }
}

private int setProgress() {
    if (mPlayer == null || mDragging) {
        return 0;
    }

    int position = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    int duration = mPlayer.getDuration();
    if (mProgress != null) {
        if (duration > 0) {
            // use long to avoid overflow
            long pos = 1000L * position / duration;
            mProgress.setProgress( (int) pos);
        }
        int percent = mPlayer.getBufferPercentage();
        mProgress.setSecondaryProgress(percent * 10);
    }

    if (mEndTime != null)
        mEndTime.setText(stringForTime(duration));
    if (mCurrentTime != null)
        mCurrentTime.setText(stringForTime(position));

    return position;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    show(sDefaultTimeout);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTrackballEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    show(sDefaultTimeout);
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (mPlayer == null) {
        return true;
    }

    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
    final boolean uniqueDown = event.getRepeatCount() == 0
            && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
    if (keyCode ==  KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK
            || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE
            || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE) {
        if (uniqueDown) {
            doPauseResume();
            show(sDefaultTimeout);
            if (mPauseButton != null) {
                mPauseButton.requestFocus();
            }
        }
        return true;
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY) {
        if (uniqueDown && !mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.start();
            updatePausePlay();
            show(sDefaultTimeout);
        }
        return true;
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_STOP
            || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE) {
        if (uniqueDown && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.pause();
            updatePausePlay();
            show(sDefaultTimeout);
        }
        return true;
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN
            || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP
            || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_MUTE) {
        // don't show the controls for volume adjustment
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        if (uniqueDown) {
            hide();
        }
        return true;
    }

    show(sDefaultTimeout);
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}

private View.OnClickListener mPauseListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        doPauseResume();
        show(sDefaultTimeout);
    }
};

private View.OnClickListener mFullscreenListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        doToggleFullscreen();
        show(sDefaultTimeout);
    }
};

public void updatePausePlay() {
    if (mRoot == null || mPauseButton == null || mPlayer == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mPauseButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
    } else {
        mPauseButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_play);
    }
}

public void updateFullScreen() {
    if (mRoot == null || mFullscreenButton == null || mPlayer == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (mPlayer.isFullScreen()) {
        mFullscreenButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_fullscreen_shrink);
    }
    else {
        mFullscreenButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_fullscreen_stretch);
    }
}

private void doPauseResume() {
    if (mPlayer == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mPlayer.pause();
    } else {
        mPlayer.start();
    }
    updatePausePlay();
}

private void doToggleFullscreen() {
    if (mPlayer == null) {
        return;
    }

    mPlayer.toggleFullScreen();
}

// There are two scenarios that can trigger the seekbar listener to trigger:
//
// The first is the user using the touchpad to adjust the posititon of the
// seekbar's thumb. In this case onStartTrackingTouch is called followed by
// a number of onProgressChanged notifications, concluded by onStopTrackingTouch.
// We're setting the field "mDragging" to true for the duration of the dragging
// session to avoid jumps in the position in case of ongoing playback.
//
// The second scenario involves the user operating the scroll ball, in this
// case there WON'T BE onStartTrackingTouch/onStopTrackingTouch notifications,
// we will simply apply the updated position without suspending regular updates.
private OnSeekBarChangeListener mSeekListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar bar) {
        show(3600000);

        mDragging = true;

        // By removing these pending progress messages we make sure
        // that a) we won't update the progress while the user adjusts
        // the seekbar and b) once the user is done dragging the thumb
        // we will post one of these messages to the queue again and
        // this ensures that there will be exactly one message queued up.
        mHandler.removeMessages(SHOW_PROGRESS);
    }

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar bar, int progress, boolean fromuser) {
        if (mPlayer == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (!fromuser) {
            // We're not interested in programmatically generated changes to
            // the progress bar's position.
            return;
        }

        long duration = mPlayer.getDuration();
        long newposition = (duration * progress) / 1000L;
        mPlayer.seekTo( (int) newposition);
        if (mCurrentTime != null)
            mCurrentTime.setText(stringForTime( (int) newposition));
    }

    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar bar) {
        mDragging = false;
        setProgress();
        updatePausePlay();
        show(sDefaultTimeout);

        // Ensure that progress is properly updated in the future,
        // the call to show() does not guarantee this because it is a
        // no-op if we are already showing.
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(SHOW_PROGRESS);
    }
};

@Override
public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    if (mPauseButton != null) {
        mPauseButton.setEnabled(enabled);
    }
    if (mFfwdButton != null) {
        mFfwdButton.setEnabled(enabled);
    }
    if (mRewButton != null) {
        mRewButton.setEnabled(enabled);
    }
    if (mNextButton != null) {
        mNextButton.setEnabled(enabled && mNextListener != null);
    }
    if (mPrevButton != null) {
        mPrevButton.setEnabled(enabled && mPrevListener != null);
    }
    if (mProgress != null) {
        mProgress.setEnabled(enabled);
    }
    disableUnsupportedButtons();
    super.setEnabled(enabled);
}

private View.OnClickListener mRewListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mPlayer == null) {
            return;
        }

        int pos = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        pos -= 5000; // milliseconds
        mPlayer.seekTo(pos);
        setProgress();

        show(sDefaultTimeout);
    }
};

private View.OnClickListener mFfwdListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mPlayer == null) {
            return;
        }

        int pos = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        pos += 15000; // milliseconds
        mPlayer.seekTo(pos);
        setProgress();

        show(sDefaultTimeout);
    }
};

private void installPrevNextListeners() {
    if (mNextButton != null) {
        mNextButton.setOnClickListener(mNextListener);
        mNextButton.setEnabled(mNextListener != null);
    }

    if (mPrevButton != null) {
        mPrevButton.setOnClickListener(mPrevListener);
        mPrevButton.setEnabled(mPrevListener != null);
    }
}

public void setPrevNextListeners(View.OnClickListener next, View.OnClickListener prev) {
    mNextListener = next;
    mPrevListener = prev;
    mListenersSet = true;

    if (mRoot != null) {
        installPrevNextListeners();

        if (mNextButton != null && !mFromXml) {
            mNextButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if (mPrevButton != null && !mFromXml) {
            mPrevButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}

public interface MediaPlayerControl {
    void    start();
    void    pause();
    int     getDuration();
    int     getCurrentPosition();
    void    seekTo(int pos);
    boolean isPlaying();
    int     getBufferPercentage();
    boolean canPause();
    boolean canSeekBackward();
    boolean canSeekForward();
    boolean isFullScreen();
    void    toggleFullScreen();
}

private static class MessageHandler extends Handler {
    private final WeakReference<VideoControllerView> mView; 

    MessageHandler(VideoControllerView view) {
        mView = new WeakReference<VideoControllerView>(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        VideoControllerView view = mView.get();
        if (view == null || view.mPlayer == null) {
            return;
        }

        int pos;
        switch (msg.what) {
            case FADE_OUT:
                view.hide();
                break;
            case SHOW_PROGRESS:
                pos = view.setProgress();
                if (!view.mDragging && view.mShowing && view.mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    msg = obtainMessage(SHOW_PROGRESS);
                    sendMessageDelayed(msg, 1000 - (pos % 1000));
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: are you running your program in android emulator

Comment: @Auto-Droid ツ
s i'm doing like that only.After completing that only i can test in real device.if i play mp4 files the controller shows ending time(duration) in "-56.-34" like this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android MediaPlayer Problems :"Error (-38 , 0) " and "stop called in state 1"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913108/android-mediaplayer-problems-error-38-0-and-stop-called-in-state-1)

Answer (score 1):

The error no. -38 corresponds to INVALID_OPERATION from MediaPlayer::start. Please note that INVALID_OPERATION is set to -ENOSYS which is -38 from errno.h.

You may have to investigate why your MediaPlayer is in an erroneous state.

You seem to try to start the playing before the preparation is complete. Use the setOnPreparedListener() method to set a preparation listener and call the start() method only after the preparation is complete.

```
  mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
   public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
     mp.start();
   }
    });
   mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

And remove the current mediaPlayer.start() invocation from the code.

Comment: It shows MediaPlayer Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer..error(-38,0)
I have changed the code like this


// Implement MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    controller.setMediaPlayer(this);
    controller.setAnchorView((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.videoSurfaceContainer));
    mp.start();
}
// End MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is the only scenario you get this error?

You need to set more listeners on the player so you could get more details:

essentials is the following:

```
        mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            Log.i("VideoPlayerManager", "Error code (what): " + what);
            if (what == 100) {
                mVideoView.stopPlayback();
                mVideoView.start();
                enforcedStop = true;
            } else if (what == 1) {
                mVideoView.stopPlayback();
                mVideoView.start();
                enforcedStop = true;

            } else if (what == 800) {
                mVideoView.stopPlayback();
                mVideoView.start();
                enforcedStop = true;

            } else if (what == 701) {
                mVideoView.stopPlayback();
                mVideoView.start();
                enforcedStop = true;

            } else if (what == 700) {
                mVideoView.stopPlayback();
                mVideoView.start();
                enforcedStop = true;
            } else if (what == -38) {
                mVideoView.stopPlayback();
                mVideoView.start();
                enforcedStop = true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Another ones should be the oncompletion listener as follows:

```
mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            if (enforcedStop) {
                enforcedStop = false;
                return;
            }
            // setLooping(true) did not work, so we use this 2 lines of code
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
```