# Android MediaPlayer Error (1, -38) and (-38, 0)

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I am working with the MediaPlayer component and I am getting the errors (1, -38) and (-38, 0). I am using    player.prepareAsync() and I call player.start() in the onPrepared() method. The curious is that I am getting the error when I reproduce a video for fourth time. I have no idea about what is happening. Anyone can help me?

This is my code:

```
public class VideoPlayerActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, VideoControllerView.MediaPlayerControl, OnCompletionListener, OnErrorListener {

SurfaceView videoSurface;
MediaPlayer player;
VideoControllerView controller;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.video_player);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    if(player != null) {
        player.release();
        player = null;
    }
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    controller= new VideoControllerView(this);

    try {
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        String path = getIntent().getStringExtra(Constants.PATH);
        player.setDataSource(path);
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        player.setOnErrorListener(this);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    videoSurface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.videoSurface);
    SurfaceHolder videoHolder = videoSurface.getHolder();
    videoHolder.addCallback(this);
    player.prepareAsync();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(player != null) {
        player.stop();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        if(player != null) {
            player.stop();
        }
        finish();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    controller.show();
    return false;
}


@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    controller.setMediaPlayer(this);
    controller.setAnchorView((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.videoSurfaceContainer));
    player.start();
}

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    player.setDisplay(holder);
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

}


@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    if(!controller.isStopped()) {
        finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MediaListActivity.class);
        String path = getIntent().getStringExtra(Constants.PATH);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.PATH, path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf(Constants.SLASH)));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    if(what == 100 || what == 1 || what == -38) {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        player = null;
        finish();

    }
    return false;
}
```

And the LogCat:

```
02-23 12:00:39.184: E/MediaPlayer(31647): error (1, -38)
02-23 12:00:39.184: E/MediaPlayer(31647): Error (1,-38)
02-23 12:00:39.184: E/MediaPlayer(31647): stop called in state 0
02-23 12:00:39.184: E/MediaPlayer(31647): error (-38, 0)
```

Comment: Same problem here, when using DRM content. After random (4-10) re-plays the playback fails with this error (1, -38) Found any fix?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android MediaPlayer Problems :"Error (-38 , 0) " and "stop called in state 1"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913108/android-mediaplayer-problems-error-38-0-and-stop-called-in-state-1)