# Getting Error in Media Player: SeekTo in wrong state: & start called in state 0

Tags: android, media-player

i am facing some issue in media player when i use as service.

**1.**  If i initialize Media Player Object in Activity as static and further use in service class then its show me this  `error (-38, 0)` , `Attempt to perform seekTo in wrong state: mPlayer=0x0, mCurrentState=0` , `start called in state 0`.

**2.** If i initialize Media Player Object in Service class and user in activity for more 
action its show's me `Null Pointer`.

```
public static MediaPlayer mPlayer = null;
```

**play Click Event**

```
    Audio_Player_Play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (mPlayer == null)
            {

                Intent Play_Intent = new Intent(RDS_Singel_Audio.this,
                        Audio_Player.class);

                startService(Play_Intent);
                Audio_Player_Play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Audio_Player_Pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else
            {
                // Play_Streaming();
                mPlayer.seekTo(mPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                mPlayer.start();
                Audio_Player_Play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Audio_Player_Pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
```

**Pause Click Event**

```
Audio_Player_Pause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Play_Streaming();
                // checking is medai player running

                Audio_Player_Play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Audio_Player_Pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                // checking is audio playing in background
                if (mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPlaying())
                {
                    mPlayer.pause();
                    /*
                     * Intent Pause_Intent = new Intent(RDS_Singel_Audio.this,
                     * Audio_Player.class); stopService(Pause_Intent);
                     */
                    Audio_Player_Play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Audio_Player_Pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
```

**OnResume() - OnPause() -OnDistroy()**

```
@Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
    }
@Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        // cleanUp();
        if (mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;

        }

        super.onPause();
    }
@Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        cleanUp();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

private void cleanUp()
    {
        if (mPlayer != null)
        {
            mVisualizerView.release();
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
        }
    }
```

**Service.Java**

```
public class Audio_Player extends Service
{
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";

    // public static MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    Function f;
    RDS_Singel_Audio sa;
    MediaPlayer mPlayer;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        try
        {
            sa = new RDS_Singel_Audio();
            Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            sa.mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            sa.mPlayer.setDataSource(sa.Audio_URL);
            sa.mPlayer.prepare();// might take long! (for buffering, etc)
            sa.mVisualizerView.link(sa.mPlayer);
            sa.mPlayer.start();
            sa.addLineRenderer();
            sa.mPlayer.setLooping(false); // Set looping

            // sa.mPlayer.start();

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.d(TAG, "" + e);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
        if (sa.mPlayer != null)
        {
            sa.mPlayer.stop();
            sa.mPlayer.release();

        }
        sa.mPlayer = null;

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");

        // mPlayer.setDataSource("http://clients.ncrypted.net/riddimapp/images/audio/4/df9919ccb2880933c795f43d735cf9bc.mp3");

    }

}
```

I found some [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008770/media-player-called-in-state-0-error-38-0) about same issue but I don't know how solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I see this part of your code, but it is not clear what you are trying to achieve. You are trying to make the player go to its current position, but it is already at that position? You could remove that part then.

```
// Play_Streaming();
mPlayer.seekTo(mPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
```

Also, on your onpause you're releasing the player, but not generating it again on your onresume. You can recreate it there with code from that link you provided:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
    }
@Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        // cleanUp();
        if (mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;

        }

        super.onPause();
    }
```

Also, as you seem to be setting the source of the mediaplayer to be an url, you should change the prepare for a prepareAsync in the following part, so that it buffers:

```
sa.mPlayer.setDataSource(sa.Audio_URL);
sa.mPlayer.prepare();// might take long! (for buffering, etc)
```

The link you provided already has a lot of suggestions for overcoming these problems above.
Please try the code on that link, especially the ones that suggest prepareAsync and the onprepared listener. Then you can get back here if it does not work.