# Android mediaplayer Error code (-38,0)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, soundcloud

I am trying to play a media file on my android app.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Runnable {


    private  static final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    //private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private TextView pauseicon;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pauseicon = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_PlayPause);
        //progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        //getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        pauseicon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String res = "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/84973999/stream?client_id=cd9d2e5604410d714e32642a4ec0eed4";

                //final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
                try {

                    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    mp.setDataSource(res);
                    mp.prepare();


                    //mp.start();
                    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            mp.start();

                        }
                    });


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    //When audio is done will change pause to play
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        pauseicon.setText("Play file again");
                    }
                });

            }
        });


        /**
         * Play button click event
         * plays a song and changes button to pause image
         * pauses a song and changes button to play image
         * */




        pauseicon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // No need to check if it is pauseicon

                if(mp.isPlaying()){
                    mp.pause();
                    ((TextView) v).setText("play");

                } else {
                    mp.start();
                    ((TextView) v).setText("pause");
                }}});



    }

    /*

    //To update progress bar
    public void run() {
        int currentPosition= 0;
        int total = mp.getDuration();
        while (mp!=null && currentPosition<=total) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                currentPosition= mp.getCurrentPosition();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return;
            }            
            progressBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
        }
    }*/
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);


            if (mp != null)
                if(mp.isPlaying())
                    mp.stop();

            mp.release();

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }
    @Override 
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if (mp != null){
            if(mp.isPlaying())
                mp.stop();

            mp.release();
        }

        //there is no reason to call super.finish(); here
        //call super.onBackPressed(); and it will finish that activity for you
        super.onBackPressed(); 

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }}
```

I am getting `11-25 15:36:48.319: E/MediaPlayer(11800): Error (-38,0)`

**Manisfest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.demosc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.demosc.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Media Player called in state 0, error (-38,0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008770/media-player-called-in-state-0-error-38-0)

Comment: Why do you prepare your Media Player in your pauseicon's OnClickListener? This doesn't make sense. Even if you fix the issue answered by Melquiades, you'd still have to press pause before pressing play.

Comment: as @Melquiades has pointed out, your onclick is being overridden by second one, so no onPrepare is being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting your onClickListener, where you setup your MediaPlayer:

```
pauseicon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
//code
```

but then, you are doing this:

```
pauseicon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // No need to check if it is pauseicon

            if(mp.isPlaying()){
                mp.pause();
                ((TextView) v).setText("play");

            } else {
                mp.start();
                ((TextView) v).setText("pause");
            }}});
```

which will overwrite onClickListener you set before. So in the end, when you click pauseicon, mp.pause() is probably giving you the error, because mp has not been initialised.

**EDIT:**
Have a look at MediaPlayer example [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)

Also, when dealing with MediaPlayer, please remember that playback control of audio/video files and streams is managed as a state machine, so it matters the order in which you call the methods. 
[image: MediaPlayer state diagram]

More info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

Also, as noted by ThaMe90, you might consider moving your MediaPlayer initialisation code outside your onClick() into onCreate() method, and for example enable PLAY button when onPrepare() is called.

Comment: It might be wise to make a separate notion of the [state diagram](http://developer.android.com/images/mediaplayer_state_diagram.gif) for the MediaPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

To play video from raw file use the following code

1- put all video's (.MP4) in /res/raw folder
2- inside the activiy write this code.

```
   Uri video;
   VideoView videoHolder = new VideoView(this);
   setContentView(videoHolder);
   video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()
+ "/" + R.raw.xXXX);

  videoHolder.setVideoURI(video);
  videoHolder.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
  public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
  jumpMain(); // jump to the next Activity
    }
});
  videoHolder.start();
   videoHolder.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                ((VideoView) v).stopPlayback();
                jumpMain();
                return true;
}
});

       } catch (Exception ex) {
        jumpMain();
    }


    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return false;
}

private synchronized void jumpMain() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ShowVideoFragment.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

}
```