# Videos of the Sample App Not Running in the Android TV Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio, android-tv

The videos in the sample app (AndroidTV Leanback Support Library sample for videos - https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback) do not play in the Android TV emulator. I'm running the app on an Android_TV_1080p_API_21 emulator. What could be wrong?

**Edit:** I'm getting the following log output:

```
2247-2260/com.example.android.tvleanback E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -38)
2247-2247/com.example.android.tvleanback E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-38)
2247-2247/com.example.android.tvleanback E/MediaPlayer﹕ stop called in state 0
2247-2247/com.example.android.tvleanback E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
2247-2247/com.example.android.tvleanback W/MediaPlayer﹕ mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
```

Comment: Do you get any kind of error? Or just a black screen?

Comment: I'm getting the error message: "Can't play this video"

Comment: What architecture is the AVD using? ARM or x86? Did you try changing that?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the same error on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method:1**
You need to call mediaPlayer.start() in the onPrepared method by using a listener "OnPreparedListener()". You are getting this error because you are calling mediaPlayer.start() before it has reached the prepared state.

Here is how you can do it :

```
mp.setDataSource(url); 
mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
mp.prepareAsync();

public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
    player.start();
}
```

**Method 2:**
It seems like Error -38 means a state-exception (as the error-message indicates). For example if you call start(), before the song was ready, or when you call pause(), even if the song isn't playing at all.

To fix this issue check the state of the mediaPlayer before calling the methods. For example:

```
if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
    mediaPlayer.pause();
}
```

Additionally, the MediaPlayer is sending event-messages. Even if you do not need the prepared-event (although it would be a good idea to not start the playback before this event was fired) you must set a callback-listener. This also holds true for the OnErrorListener, OnCompletionListener, OnPreparedListener and OnSeekCompletedListener (if you call the seek method).

Listeners can be attached simply by

```
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // Do something. For example: playButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
});
```

**Source Link:-**[Media Player called in state 0, error (-38,0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008770/media-player-called-in-state-0-error-38-0)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I have not tried it yet, will do it and let you know. I am awarding the bounty to you.

Comment: @burakk i have the same issue i could not be able to play video in android TV emulator api level 21 it always showing black screen can u pls help me how you have fix it.