# About mp3 player

Tags: android

I'm working on a simple Mp3 player. `A.mp3` is at the sdcard.

When I click the button **play** noting happens, why?

I don't know what's wrong with it.

Here's the `MainActivity` file:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
       private Button play;
       private Button pause;
       private Button stop;
       private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        play =(Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
        pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        play.setOnClickListener(this);
        pause.setOnClickListener(this);
        stop.setOnClickListener(this);

        initMediaPlayer(); 

    }
    private void initMediaPlayer()
    {
        try {
            File file =new   File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"A.mp3");
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(file.getPath());
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.play:
            if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.start(); 
            }
            break;
        case R.id.pause:
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.pause(); 
            }
            break;
        case R.id.stop:
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.reset(); 
                initMediaPlayer();
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();

        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    }

 }
```

Here is the `Layout` file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Play" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/pause"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Pause" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/stop"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Stop" />
```

I found that the path of sdcard is "/storage/sdcard1/". so I use mediaPlayer.setDataSource("/storage/sdcard1/A.mp3");But it's the same..setDataSource did not run

Comment: Can you post your xml where the buttons are defined?

Comment: I have post the xml..

Comment: Did you check if your application enters the cases?

Comment: in your onClick()-method : When you press the play button, does he go in the R.id.play case or in the default? Did you check this?

Comment: It must be the path problem.

Comment: @user3956566 Tag MediaPlayer start called in state 0;Tag MediaPlayer error(-38,0)

Comment: No..I am newbee..I have no idea what to do = =

Comment: @TheTanic It go in the R.id.play case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by your replies in the comments, I have updated my answer.
1..

```
private void initMediaPlayer()
{
    try {
        File file =new   File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"A.mp3");
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(file.getPath());
        mediaPlayer.prepare(); // Replace this line.

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You could try using

```
public void prepareAsync ()
```

instead of prepare. As prepare() uses synchronous threading which can block the program.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepareAsync()

Keep using the Async Prepare method, it is more efficient.

2..
Also if you set an `OnErrorListener`, this will check for errors when you are setting the data source.

```
public void setOnErrorListener (MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener listener)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnErrorListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener%29

3..
If you are showing up an error:

```
Tag MediaPlayer start called in state 0;Tag MediaPlayer error(-38,0)
```

This is showing that the state of the MediaPlayer is not inialised. You can see the states here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

4..
Ensure that you have your parameter to set data source in the correct format:

> setDataSource(FileDescriptor), or setDataSource(String), or
>   setDataSource(Context, Uri), or setDataSource(FileDescriptor, long,
>   long) transfers a MediaPlayer object in the Idle state to the
>   Initialized state.

5..
Then using an `OnPrepared()` Listener http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener.html

You can then safely call `mediaplayer.start()`

6..
Also see this question [Media Player called in state 0, error (-38,0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008770/media-player-called-in-state-0-error-38-0)

7..
If this doesn't fix the problem, let me know.

Comment: I use Log.d().And I found that initMediaPlayer() did not run.why?

Comment: I've try,it's the same.

Comment: Thanks so much..I found that .mediaPlayer.setDataSource() did not run,So maybe the path is wrong..I use android handset to launch the app..I don't know where do I put the A.mp3 file..I just copy from computer into the sdcard.

Comment: Thanks ...I've read..But I still don't know how to get the correct path of my A.mp3..I just put it in sdcard.But I am not sure the correct path of the sdcard.I've try many paths I searched on the website,but still not working...