# How to find the right file path in sdcard?

Tags: android, datasource, android-mediaplayer

This is the previous post.
[About mp3 player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30914971/about-mp3-player)
And the picture below is my A.mp3 path I find in my phone.
`
[image: screenshot]

```
  mediaPlayer.setDataSource("/storage/sdcard1/A.mp3")
```

---

```
  File file =new   File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"A.mp3");
  mediaPlayer.setDataSource(file.getPath());
```

---

### There are two paths above..According the picture,it should be the first one,but it does not work.

I push A.mp3 into the internal storage,and play is ok.

```
  mediaPlayer.setDataSource("/system/A.mp3");
```

Comment: I've try 4 or 5 paths.But you can see the picture,/storage/sdcard1/ seems to the right one,it did not work .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly- Check that the SD card is mounted and readable.

```
if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED));
```

or

```
if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY));
```

From your [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30914971/about-mp3-player): You are using:

```
File file =new   File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"A.mp3");
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(file.getPath());
```

and have tried:

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource("/storage/sdcard1/A.mp3")
```

Then try:

Edit: add in Music folder.

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource("/sdcard1/Music/A.mp3");
```

Also: this http://www.bogotobogo.com/Android/android24Media.php#SDCard is an interesting link. So you can explore you files in Android Studio.

Comment: the post's date is 2010..It's kinda different from then

Comment: It's a little late..I will try If ().equals() tomorrow..Thanks

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) is true

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY) is false.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I finally find that the two files got different permission.I don't know what do those "wrdrrwrwrwrw*****" mean.So I need to search it .

Comment: I did not put permissions in my manifest,but I can play A,mp3 when the path is "/storage/A.mp3"

Comment: Look at what files?I have two sdcard dir.On the picture above you can see sdcard0 and sdcard1.I don't know what's different

Comment: The sdcard1's directories are what I can see directly from my computer

Comment: And I use adb shell to see the sdcard0's list.There are some floders that sdcard1 also have.

Comment: What kind of chat tool do you use..I got some strange problems to ask..and I need to send picture to you..But it's a little inconvenient here.

Answer (score 1):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This permission was forgotten.Now is ok