# MediaPlayer error code (-38,0) getDuration

Tags: android

I am currently trying to design a simple app that streams an Music Player. I have the URL for the song and am setting up the `MediaPlayer` like as below. Everything is OK at first song, but when i play an other song, The program isn't crashing when emulated, but nothing is playing and I am get the following error:

```xml
E/MediaPlayer: Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer
E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
```

**PlayerService.java**

```java
public class MusicPlayerService extends Service {
    private SongItem mSong;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mSong = ListSong.getListSong().get(ListSong.getSelectedItem());
        registerLocalFilter();
        playMedia();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void playMedia() {
        if (handler == null) {
            thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Looper.prepare();
                    handler = new Handler();
                    handler.post(playAudioFromURL);
                    Looper.loop();
                }
            });
            thread.start();
        } else {
            handler.post(playAudioFromURL);
        }
    }

    private Runnable playAudioFromURL = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(mSong.getSongUrl());
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(onPreparedListener);
                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletionListener);
                mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(onSeekCompleteListener);
                mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(onErrorListener);
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.w(TAG, "playAudioFromURL: " + e.toString());
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                Log.w(TAG, "playAudioFromURL: " + ex.toString());
            } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                Log.w(TAG, "playAudioFromURL: " + ex.toString());
            }
        }
    };


    private MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener onPreparedListener = new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            ListSong.setPlaying(true);
            sendLoadComplete();
            updateTimer();
            mp.start();
        }
    };
}
```

I have write `mp.start()` in `onPrepared()` and using `mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();` like solution at [Media Player called in state 0, error (-38,0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008770/media-player-called-in-state-0-error-38-0) but it's not working.

Please help me!

Answer (score 2):

Before `mediaPlayer.setDataSource(mSong.getSongUrl());` in MediaPlayer `mediaPlayer.reset();`  it may be resolve your problem.

Comment: **may** ? then it should be in comment dude!

Answer (score 0):

hope it'll help someone

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.reset();
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(songURL);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(mp -> {
                mp.start();
                updateProgressBar();
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```