# How to play HD videos (720p or 1080p) play in Video view in OS version 4.2.2?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have been developing video advertisement android app, but I need one help to play HD videos in `VideoView` in android version 4.2.2.
I have download the all the videos in internal storage and I have to play this video in one screen like this

[image: I have download the all the videos in internal storage and I have to play this video in one screen like this]

But now some video is in Full HD and that video is not playing in video view in specially android version 4.2.2 and detect the error like this

> E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)

so what should I do, I have search many things or many github libraries like `ExoPlayer` , `EasyPlayer` but in this library is also not playing Full HD Videos in android version 4.2.2.

I need help.


I have been playing video in `VideoView` with following code.

```
MediaController controller = new MediaController(this);
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(pathVideo));
        videoView.setMediaController(controller);
        controller.setMediaPlayer(vv);
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener((MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener) mContext);
        videoView.setOnCompletionListener((MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener) mContext);
        videoView.setOnErrorListener((MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener) mContext);
        videoView.start();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Media Player called in state 0, error (-38,0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008770/media-player-called-in-state-0-error-38-0)

Comment: I don't think so because when I play law resolution type of video like 320p,420p then it's play fine in video view using this code.

Comment: This error (-38,0) and Can't play video error show when I play HD videos like 720p and 1080p I have attached the sample video link to get an idea about video resolution Link : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44rTTLjZZz4

Comment: Have you tested the answer in the possible duplicate? There is a huge difference in memory usage between 420p and 720p and that is what the `MediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener()` and `MediaPlayer.prepareAsync()` are doing. Caching the video so it can be played without a crash. Simply calling `.start()` is not good enough for HD video.

Comment: ok have to do this MediaPlayer.prepareAsync() in  comman method of onPrepared like this @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
                mp = new MediaPlayer();
            }
            mp.prepareAsync();
            mp.start();
    }                                                                                        but now detect one more error is : E/MediaPlayer: prepareAsync called in state 8

Comment: Finally i get the libraries for playing HD video in android version 4.2.2, Link : https://github.com/tcking/GiraffePlayer , But now i have facing one more issue is when i play two video in same screen than at the time any one video is play another video stay on push mode so how i do this? to play two video at the same time.