# How can I ask Android MediaPlayer not to play after onPrepared?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-mediaplayer

I am working on an Android application which does lots of concurrencies and RxJava treading in the background and it is possible to not want to play a music which is in the async preparation phase for some reason:

```
player.prepareAsync()
```

and

```
override fun onPrepared(mp: MediaPlayer?) {
    isPreparing = false

    if (playAfterPreparing) {
        //start playback
        mp?.start()
    } else {
        // don't play and keep it prepare for later!!!
    }

    updateNotification()
}
```

but the problem is after preparation you should play(!) because:
[Media Player called in state 0, error (-38,0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008770/media-player-called-in-state-0-error-38-0)

I even tried to start and pause one after another in preparation:

```
override fun onPrepared(mp: MediaPlayer?) {
    Timber.i("onPrepared")
    Timber.i("playAfterPreparing: $playAfterPreparing")

    isPreparing = false

    //start playback
    mp?.start()

    if (!playAfterPreparing) {
        mp?.pause()
    }

    updateNotification()
}
```

but it didn't work cause it rendered to the same issue.

I also know how MediaPlayer state machine is working, but don't see anything in this situation in documents:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

any solution for such a situation?

Comment: `after preparation you should play(!)` no. No errors appear if you don't start playback when prepared. It is likely caused by some other reason

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko this is exactly the behavior I suppose to see! but as I mentioned in question according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008770/media-player-called-in-state-0-error-38-0 I always get -38 error!

Comment: I still think that you get that error for some other reason. Nobody knows what else you are doing with your mediaplayer.

Comment: ok, if you think so, I will write a simple app with only one MediaPlayer to test.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko you were correct! I create a very simple app with only one MediaPlayer and it worked for me. I will investigate more what was exactly my issue and will post it here. By the way, in my app I was using local music but in my simple test I tested with online streaming.

Comment: local VS online should not matter

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko you are correct, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @VladyslavMatviienko comments, I suspected that I am doing something wrong somewhere else and he was correct. According to [Android MediaPlayer document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html):

[image: Android MediaPlayer State Diagram]

It is possible to stay in `Prepared` state, but it is not possible to call any method namely `pause()` and that was my fault. In `Prepared` state You can only call `start()`, `seekTo()` or `stop()`.

Hope this answer comes handy for those who might face this issue later.