# Streaming WebRadio

Tags: android

I want to stream a webradio channels but android MediaPlayer Supports only streaming of files that are in downloadable form.

Anybody have solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can play the [web radio stations as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681550/android-2-2-mediaplayer-is-working-fine-with-one-shoutcast-url-but-not-with-the). 
Please note that the "audio/aacp streaming is not supported directly" so you have two solutions:

1- Use some decoder

2- Use some local Streaming Proxy

[For detail about above two points please see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671479/android-mediaplayer-works-fine-in-our-custom-audio-streaming-application-up-to-a).

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the RTSP servers to do it, e.g. Wowza works just fine and there are many other rtsp servers out there. You might want also some encoder, adobe live encoder with AAC plugin is a good option.