# Playing m3u8 on Android Froyo using FFmpeg

Tags: android, http, ffmpeg, live, android-2.2-froyo

I need to create an http live streaming client in Android froyo without being dependent on 3rd party applications (e.g Vitamio).  I am able to configure and build Bambuser's release of FFmpeg using Android ndk r7. My problem is I don't know how to use it.

I found sample codes here in stackoverflow and other forums where people are able to play .avi/.mp3 files from a url using av_open_input_file().  My question is, is it the same for m3u8 files? Or, do i need to use other functions to be able to work around them? I don't know how to begin.

Note: I am an android developer.  My C programming is a little bit weak.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681550/android-2-2-mediaplayer-is-working-fine-with-one-shoutcast-url-but-not-with-the

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671479/android-mediaplayer-works-fine-in-our-custom-audio-streaming-application-up-to-a

Comment: Thanks Yaqub. but this isn't what i'm looking for.  http live streaming is not natively supported yet in android froyo (api level 8). that's why i need ffmpeg.

Comment: StreamProxy class is here:http://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/source/browse/Npr/src/org/npr/android/news/StreamProxy.java

Comment: Have you already found some example? I have the same problem...