# How to play video using FFMPEG library in Android?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, java-native-interface, frame

I was able to build `ffmpeg` library by using [rock player build script](http://www.rockplayer.com/tech_en.html).

Now I have this `.so` file, how do I play video? And I want to display this video inside a small `LinearLayout` in my `Activity`.

Is it possible?

Update:
I know that it's easy to play video using `VideoView` or `MediaPlayer` + `SurfaceView`.  I just wanted to understand more about `ffmpeg` library and how to display the frames inside an Android `Activity`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681550/android-2-2-mediaplayer-is-working-fine-with-one-shoutcast-url-but-not-with-the

Comment: thanks Yaqub! the link you provided is about audio streaming but it led me to the right answer.

Comment: I wanted to, but sorry my reputation is below 15

Comment: @Macchiato, so what was the right answer?

Comment: please help me how to combine an image and an audio clip to make a video clip. I am really struggling!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this player: https://github.com/bbcallen/ijkplayer

Basically what you need to do is build a JNI interface through to the MediaPlayer class (or possibly ExoPlayer in newer Android though I haven't done this yet).

If you look at the repo link you will see that this needs to be done on top of ffplay more than ffmpeg as the former is the player and the latter the decode/encode/package tool.

Comment: Working, but uses software decoding in my case - but much better than VideoView for RTP stream stability wise.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of doing this. You should have a look at Dolphin Player, an open source media player for Android. Its actually rather complex, you could also look at the VLC source code which makes use of FFMPEG but VLC is an extensive very complete wrapper to play videos.

Answer (score 0):

See for example an Android app in github: https://github.com/havlenapetr/FFMpeg. This project may be somewhat outdated, but its part that is responsible for video display is quite understandable. You can look for more recent contributions on github.