# MediaPlayer refusing to prepare on some phones

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MediaPlayer unable to prepare?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372073/mediaplayer-unable-to-prepare)

Title says it all. I wrote a streaming radio app that is fairly basic in functionality but some devices refuse to "prepare" such as my Optimus One running 2.2. My app runs on other 2.2 devices any my brother's S2 running 2.3 and my Prime running 4.0.3.

Any idea why my specific devise will not prepare the audio?

Edit: Added some code below

```
private void togglePlay() {
    try {
        if(!this.player.isPlaying()) {
            this.player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            this.player.setDataSource(this.address);
            this.player.prepareAsync();
        } else {
            this.player.reset();
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        ;
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        ;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ;
    }
}
```

Edit: Added ADB log

```
03-09 08:17:26.933: I/ActivityManager(1352): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.landonmanning.mediaplayer.celestiaradio/.Media }
03-09 08:17:27.003: V/PVPlayer(1281): PVPlayer constructor
03-09 08:17:27.003: V/PVPlayer(1281): construct PlayerDriver
03-09 08:17:27.003: V/PlayerDriver(1281): constructor
03-09 08:17:27.013: V/PlayerDriver(1281): OpenCore hardware module loaded
03-09 08:17:27.013: V/PlayerDriver(1281): start player thread
03-09 08:17:27.023: V/PlayerDriver(1281): startPlayerThread
03-09 08:17:27.023: V/PlayerDriver(1281): InitializeForThread
03-09 08:17:27.023: V/PlayerDriver(1281): OMX_MasterInit
03-09 08:17:27.043: V/PlayerDriver(1281): OsclScheduler::Init
03-09 08:17:27.043: V/PlayerDriver(1281): CreatePlayer
03-09 08:17:27.083: V/PlayerDriver(1281): AddToScheduler
03-09 08:17:27.083: V/PlayerDriver(1281): PendForExec
03-09 08:17:27.083: V/PlayerDriver(1281): OsclActiveScheduler::Current
03-09 08:17:27.083: V/PlayerDriver(1281): StartScheduler
03-09 08:17:27.093: V/PVPlayer(1281): send PLAYER_SETUP
03-09 08:17:27.093: V/PlayerDriver(1281): Send player code: 2
03-09 08:17:27.093: V/PlayerDriver(1281): CommandCompleted
03-09 08:17:27.093: V/PlayerDriver(1281): Completed command PLAYER_SETUP status=PVMFSuccess
03-09 08:17:27.093: V/PVPlayer(1281): setDataSource(http://molestia.ponify.me:8062)
03-09 08:17:27.093: V/PVPlayer(1281): prepareAsync
03-09 08:17:27.093: V/PVPlayer(1281):   data source = http://molestia.ponify.me:8062
03-09 08:17:27.103: V/PlayerDriver(1281): Send player code: 3
03-09 08:17:27.103: V/PlayerDriver(1281): handleSetDataSource
03-09 08:17:27.103: V/PlayerDriver(1281): handleSetDataSource- scanning for extension
03-09 08:17:27.193: V/PlayerDriver(1281): CommandCompleted
03-09 08:17:27.193: V/PlayerDriver(1281): Completed command PLAYER_SET_DATA_SOURCE status=PVMFSuccess
03-09 08:17:27.193: V/PVPlayer(1281): run_init s=0, cancelled=0
03-09 08:17:27.193: V/PlayerDriver(1281): Send player code: 6
03-09 08:17:27.193: V/PlayerDriver(1281): release string is 2.2 len 3
03-09 08:17:27.453: D/StatusBarPolicy(1352): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 3
03-09 08:17:27.453: D/StatusBarPolicy(1352): [BRIGHTHY] curNetwork=302220 curHPLMN=302220
03-09 08:17:27.903: I/ActivityManager(1352): Displayed activity com.landonmanning.mediaplayer.celestiaradio/.Media: 951 ms (total 4183 ms)
03-09 08:17:28.123: V/PlayerDriver(1281): HandleInformationalEvent: PVMFInfoErrorHandlingStart
03-09 08:17:28.123: V/PlayerDriver(1281): HandleInformationalEvent: type=26 UNHANDLED
03-09 08:17:28.123: W/MediaPlayer(20004): info/warning (1, 26)
03-09 08:17:28.123: I/MediaPlayer(20004): Info (1,26)
03-09 08:17:28.133: V/PlayerDriver(1281): CommandCompleted
03-09 08:17:28.133: V/PlayerDriver(1281): Completed command PLAYER_INIT status=PVMFFailure
03-09 08:17:28.133: E/PlayerDriver(1281): Command PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or info PVMFFailure, -1
03-09 08:17:28.133: E/MediaPlayer(20004): error (1, -1)
03-09 08:17:28.133: E/MediaPlayer(20004): Error (1,-1)
03-09 08:17:28.133: V/PVPlayer(1281): run_set_video_surface s=-2147483648, cancelled=0
03-09 08:17:28.133: V/PlayerDriver(1281): HandleInformationalEvent: PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete
03-09 08:17:28.133: W/PlayerDriver(1281): PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete
```