# Android MediaPlayer Error Code

Tags: android

I am receiving a weird error when trying to play a stream with mediaPlayer.. I can't think of anything I have changed to cause this error, it just started happening. Here is what the logcat says:

```
02-26 20:04:00.979: E/MediaPlayer(403): error (1, -1004)
02-26 20:04:01.219: E/MediaPlayer(403): Error (1,-1004)
02-26 20:04:01.219: E/MEDIAPLAYER ERRORS(403): what: 1  extra: -1004
```

I can't find any documentation on the error code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681550/android-2-2-mediaplayer-is-working-fine-with-one-shoutcast-url-but-not-with-the

Comment: It's not a shoutcast stream, it is just an mp3 file located on my web server. It only occurs in the 2.2 emulator from what I have experienced. It works fine on my 4.0 phone..

Comment: remove proxy from computer then run on emulator

Comment: What do you mean? I don't think I have a proxy

Answer (score 1):

You can find some documentation on the error codes here: https://github.com/android/platform_external_opencore/blob/master/pvmi/pvmf/include/pvmf_return_codes.h

Answer (score 0):

These are error codes from `android.media.MediaPlayer`. You can find the documentation here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener (the callback definition has the definitions linked). This won't help you with the specific cause of your error, but hopefully this will get you started.